# Write a function factorial_list(Arr) in Python, which accepts a list Arr of numbers and return the list of factorial of each value

Tags: python

Output Example:-

```
Sample Input Data of the list: Arr= [1,2,3,4,5]
Sample Output Data in the List: Op = [1,2,6,24,120]
```

Edit*= sorry forgot to give what have i done so far:-

```
def factorial_list(Arr):
    for item in Arr:
        fact = 1
    for number in range(1,item+1):
        fact = fact * number
        print ("Factorial of", item, "is", fact)
l1=eval(input("Enter List: "))
factorial_list(l1)
```

here is my output:

```
Enter List: [1,2,3,4,5]
Factorial of 5 is 1
Factorial of 5 is 2
Factorial of 5 is 6
Factorial of 5 is 24
Factorial of 5 is 120
```

which is not my desired output what should I do to get it in my list form??

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please share where do you get stuck first.

Comment: Hint - check `math` module, `factorial` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

def factorial_list(Arr):
    ret = []
    for el in Arr:
        ret.append(math.factorial(el))
    return ret

l1=eval(input("Enter List: "))
print('Factorials:', factorial_list(l1))
```

Output:

```
Enter List: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Factorials: [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

***Edit (suggested by Daniel Hao):***

*To make this more efficient, we could use a list comprehension in the factorial_list function:*

```py
def factorial_list(Arr):
    return [math.factorial(el) for el in Arr]

l1=eval(input("Enter List: "))
print('Factorials:', factorial_list(l1))
```

Comment: You could simplify it by using List Comp. like this `result = [factorial(x) for x in Arr]`

Comment: @DanielHao for input from user as a list?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because there are square brackets in the input - and so that's the easiest way

Comment: I mean the alternative would be `[int(i) for i in input('Enter List: ')[1:-1].replace(' ', '').split(',')]` which is a lot more complicated

Answer (score 1):

```
def fact(n):
  num = 1
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    num *= i
  return num

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
out = []

for element in arr:
  out.append(fact(element))

print(out)
```

this can be more efficient but it will do the job.

to out as a list you have to make an empty list then in each loop iteration add the factorial to this list using
list.append()

then after the loop print the list
print(out).

Comment: the output is not in the form of list that is what i am aiming for here..

Comment: I was just reading it 
I shouldn't  have post a code sample

should I delete it or just give an explanation?

Comment: if you want to output as a list make an empty list for output 
and in the loop instead if printing append to the list using 
list.append(item)

then after the loop print the list 
print(list)

don't call it list

Comment: i can use an explanation, would be helpful..

Comment: @OmarMoBadr Since the OP provided his code and output, this is now a reasonable question, but the core of it seems to be "how to build the output as a list".

Comment: @Yush
to make a list in python you can use 
out = []

this will make an empty list

to add an element for ex 1 use

out.append(1)

this will add an item to the list 

to print the whole list you can print it by 

print(out)